# Edit commited migration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, migration

In my project I have migrations like:

```
 1. 20141122184434_add_column_a_to_b
 2. 20141208235304_delete_data_from_b
 3. 20141217011359_add_table
 4. 20141218183503_remove_column_b_from_c
```

And they are already commited for my develop branch (but not on master and production). After few weeks (and adding more migration) it was found that migration B contains error, and it deletes important data, so we can't merge it with master.

Is there any clean way to edit migration `20141208235304_delete_data_from_b`? I know I can just reroll, edit, and migrate again, but how will it work for other developers after I commit my changes to develop branch?

Comment: Edit migration file and remove the entry for 20141208235304 in you database table 'schema_migration' re run the migration file using "rake db:migrate version=20141208235304"

Comment: It means that all developers will need to manually delete this entry in schema_migration?

Comment: that was simplest way. Other option are you first rollback your migrate and then edit and re run.

Comment: Instead of each developer going through the same steps you can commit your changes and other developers will need to run drop, create, schema:load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the migration is recoverable (which means it will not destruct important data), then you can simply add a new migration to fix the issue.

Otherwise, if you discovered that one of the migrations is causing any issue, therefore the only possible solution is to fix the migration before it is ever applied in production. In that case, fix the migration, but then whoever applied such migration locally must:

1. reload the schema completely (`rake db:schema:load`) or
2. revert that migration (`rake db:migrate:redo` VERSION=20141208235304)

One more advice. A migration is designed to change the database schema, NOT to delete/insert or manipulate data. For such, you should use a rake task.

Comment: Yup, rake task is way to go, will know this since now. Thanks.